# how to control the extent of multi-barplot on the X-axis with GNUPLOT

Tags: gnuplot, bar-chart

I am trying to make a multi-barplot as in the attached image, but the counting on the X-axis must start from 44 up to 127 not from 1 up to 84 as it is now.
Can anyone please indicate how to do that?

```
set ylabel "Sec. Struct. Probability" offset -1
set yrange [0:1.0]
set xlabel "domain sequence"
set xrange [1:84]
set lmargin 15
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1
set border 3
set boxwidth 0.9 absolute
set style fill solid 1.00 border
set xtics out
set xtics nomirror
set x2tics out
set x2tics nomirror
set x2tic scale 0
set ytics out
set ytics nomirror
set ytics font "Times-Roman,12"
set ytics offset 0.6, 0.05
set xtics font "Times-Roman,12"
set xtics offset -0.15,0.4
set xtics scale 3
set x2tics font "Courier,10"
set x2tics offset 0,graph -1.08
set datafile separator " "
set size ratio 0.5

plot "./SS_prediction.forGNUPLOT.dat" using 3:x2ticlabel(1) lc rgb "red" fs transparent solid 0.8 noborder title "Helix", \
"" using 4 lc rgb "blue" fs transparent solid 0.8 noborder title "Beta", \
"" using 5 lc rgb "green" fs transparent solid 0.8 noborder title "PPII"
```

[image]

My data file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0dcq95mk21x4gxw/delta2d_SS_prediction.dat?dl=0)

Comment: Please also post your data file and some more information about how you want to visualize your data. It seems a bit strange too me, that you use `x2ticlabel` without having any other reference to the x2-axis. Also keep in mind, that gnuplot always starts histograms at x=0, so starting at x=44 you cut off a lot of entries etc.

Comment: You are right about GNUPLOT, it always starts histograms from x=0! Please read my rephrased question. I feel the answer is simpler now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start the histogram at x=44 you can use the `newhistogram` keyword, which allows you to specify a starting value with `at 44`:

```
set xrange [44:127]
...
plot newhistogram at 44, \
    "./SS_prediction.forGNUPLOT.dat" using 3:x2ticlabel(1) ...
```